# Convert Date into simple DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS format in SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date

I have a date passed as a string with this format:

```
Fri Dec 04 01:00:00 CST 2015
```

Anyone know how to convert it into `DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` format in Oracle? I'm trying to look for samples but can't seem to find any.

Result should be:

```
04-12-2015 01:00:00
```

(not sure if the time is right since it has CST)

I can have the string passed into Java, so if there are easier ways to transform it in Java it's fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use the below Query to get ur required output

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Fri Dec 04 01:00:00 CST 2015', 
                               'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
       FROM DUAL;
```

**OUTPUT**

04-12-2015 01:00:00

Answer (score 2):

You could parse this String from the database to `Date` in Java, by using `SimpleDateFormat`.

The correct format would be `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateFromDatabase);
```

Once you have it as a date you can format the date in any format you'd like by using a new `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
SimpleDateFormat desiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String result = desiredFormat.format(date);
```